# Edit Html Attribute Without ID

Tags: javascript, html, dom, electron, inject

Hello so I have this code

```html
<div class="ic-app-header__logomark-container">
          <a href="https://iusd.instructure.com/" class="ic-app-header__logomark __web-inspector-hide-shortcut__">
            <span class="screenreader-only">Dashboard</span>
          </a>
        </div>
```

And I want to modify the href to be javascript:void(0) how can I do this with only class and name would I have to use 
 `.ic-app-header__logomark` or something? 

Also I am injecting code into external site with electron and can only access css and javascript in one js file.

Comment: Use document.getElementsByClassName("ic-app-header__logomark __web-inspector-hide-shortcut__"). But if there are more than one link with this class, you will not be able to find out which one is the one you search. (Unless you check for the content of the link)

Comment: Thank you Sam! But there is only two elements with that class one a div one an A how do I specify content or name?

Comment: Ok Thank You! I will try this!

Comment: How do you add the thing that checks if it's a A element? I am clueless.

Comment: What do you mean with "the thing"?

Comment: I mean this ` if (element.nodeName.toLowerCase == "a")`

Comment: @esqew I did my research before asking a question I found no documentation. I'm sorry if this is a bad topic but I didn't understand it.

Comment: If you know, that there is exactly one a-element with a defined class, you could just use element = document.querySelector("a.ic-app-header__logomark-container"). You will get back a HTMLElement, which you can change with setAttribute("href", "javascript:void(0)");. But as already said by esqew, you should really try to find solutions for such a problem by learning the language. If you would just google 'javascript change href', you would have had your answer within seconds.

Comment: Thank you @Sam for the Help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `document.getElementsByClassName("ic-app-header__logomark-container")` or `document.querySelector(".ic-app-header__logomark-container")`

Comment: Thank you I will Test This! But there is two elements with that class a div and a A can I make it document.querySelector("a.ic-app-header__logomark-container")

Comment: use document.querySelectorAll(".ic-app-header__logomark-container"); then run loop because SelectorAll returns all the matching elements as an array aka collection you can do what ever you wish from there on,

Comment: Exactly, in case the class has more than one element, you have to bring them all and go through them one by one. Sorry my english, i'm argentinian. 